# Is a C# null check required prior to casting an object with "as"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've only been able to find solutions on SO for Java/ActionScript tags.  If this is a duplicate please let me know and I'll delete.

Using ASP.Net MVC 5, I'm passing a model class from ViewBag to a partial view in which it renders to a form:

```
@if (ViewBag.CourseQuoteRequest != null && ViewBag.CourseQuoteRequest as CourseQuoteRequest != null)
{
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_CourseQuoteRequest.cshtml", (CourseQuoteRequest) ViewBag.CourseQuoteRequest)
    </div>
}
```

Can the null checks be **reliably** simplified to only check for null once?  It's important (to us) that the ViewBag model exists, and is only rendered if the partial view if it is the correct class type:

```
@if (ViewBag.CourseQuoteRequest as CourseQuoteRequest != null) // Acceptable and reliable?
```

The above runs, but I'm not sure if there's any risks that are being introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as` is `null`-safe :)

If you pass `null` to `as` it will return `null`.

But it can be even more simplified with `is` operator:

```
if (ViewBag.CourseQuoteRequest is CourseQuoteRequest courseQuoteRequest)
```

and under the `if` you can safely use `courseQuoteRequest`, which will be of type `CourseQuoteRequest`.

```
@if (ViewBag.CourseQuoteRequest is CourseQuoteRequest courseQuoteRequest)
{
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_CourseQuoteRequest.cshtml", courseQuoteRequest)
    </div>
}
```

See [type pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern).

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your null check by using the `is` operator

`@if (ViewBag.CourseQuoteRequest is CourseQuoteRequest)`

Also if you need the course quote request object, you can use pattern matching

```
@if (ViewBag.CourseQuoteRequest is CourseQuoteRequest request)
{
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_CourseQuoteRequest.cshtml", request)
    </div>
}
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern) for documentation

Comment: Just to clarify, if `ViewBag.CourseQuoteRequest` was null would that still render the model, but then generate a null reference exception in the partial view?  As in, is your method also doing null checking?

Comment: The `null` check is done implicitly using the `is` operator. If your model is `null`, the partial view won't be rendered